# Displaying a video in rails through a url in database

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I would like to add YouTube embeded video with a URL that's saved with the post.

Could someone point in the right direction?

Comment: Did you try Googling [ruby on rails youtube embed](https://www.google.com/search?q=ruby+on+rails+youtube+embed)? Did you try any of the search results?

Answer (score 0):

I've done some quick research and ended looking for this solution: `https://gorails.com/forum/embed-youtube-video-in-rails-app`

With the iFrame you just need the embeded url of the video, which would look this:
`https://www.youtube.com/embed/lQOLrycmXC4`

Here is an example of implementation of the iFrame in a Rails view:

```rb
<iframe src='<%= @post.youtube_url %>?enablejsapi=1&amp;autoplay=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
```

Where `youtube_url = https://www.youtube.com/embed/lQOLrycmXC4`